# how to generate a blank coordinate table with loop in python

Tags: python

For example, I want to generate a 2x2 coordinate blank table:

```
dict = {(0,0):[],(0,1):[],(1,0):[],(1,1):[]}
```

I tried using a loop like this:

```
dict = {(i,j) for i,j in zip(range(2),range(2))}
```

but it doesn't work. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate both `i` and `j` independently, which a `zip` of two identical ranges doesn't do (it forces `i` and `j` to have the same values). You also need to supply a value for the dictionary entry:

```
dict = {(i,j) : [] for i in range(2) for j in range(2)}
print(dict)
```

Output:

```
{(0, 1): [], (1, 0): [], (0, 0): [], (1, 1): []}
```

Answer (score 1):

your version does not work:

```
>>> {(i,j) for i,j in zip(range(2),range(2))}
set([(0, 0), (1, 1)])
```

you should use something like this:

```
>>> {(i,j):[] for i in range(2) for j in range(2)}
{(0, 1): [], (1, 0): [], (0, 0): [], (1, 1): []}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.product` instead:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> {p: [] for p in product(range(2), repeat=2)}
{(0, 1): [], (1, 0): [], (0, 0): [], (1, 1): []}
>>>
```